# From field in Form to email (unknown sender)

Tags: php, forms

So I'm having trouble showing the senders full name in the From: in a form to email script.

I have this:

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name = $_POST['name'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
}

$address = "example@example.com, example@example.com";


$e_subject =  '' . $name . ' has confirmed their attendance.';


$e_body = "$name blah blah blah blah" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "Please do not reply to this email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $name" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Success!</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

It works if only one word/name is entered in the name field but as soon as their is two or more words it shows (unknown sender).

I could split the names into two fields but I really don't want to do that.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using PHP's mail function or something like PEAR Mail?

Comment: You are putting unsanitized external data into an email header…

Answer (score 0):

The From-Field in the EMail-Header is defined in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). There should go an email-address. You can use more email-addresses when they are comma-separated. If you want to display names in the From-Header then you have to do this according to the mentioned RFC. As I haven't read the full RFC, I can only say, how this might work, but I think it will work this way:

```
"Name Surname" <email@domain.tld>
```

This means for your code:

```
$headers = "From: \"$name\" <$email>" . PHP_EOL;
```